# Double cannot be dereferenced,parsing a 2D array

Tags: java

I keep getting a double cannot be dereferenced error when compiling my code. Here is the code I wrote to parse through a 2D array

```
    /*
     * calcCarbonFootprints
     *
     * Purpose: calculates carbon foot print of each person in a population
     *   and store the result in the corresponding index of the 1D result array
     *
     * Parameters:  double[] - a 2D array of data for a populution where,
     *                each row represents an individual in the population and
     *                each column of a row has the following data for that individual:
     *                  -fuel efficiency of their car
     *                  -average kms driven per day
     *                  -the age of their car
     *                  -average kms on transit per day
     *              int[] - a 1D array to store the total carbon footprint for each individual
     *
     * Preconditions: none
     *
     * Returns: void
     *  
     */
    // TODO
        public static void calcCarbonFootprints ( double[] data, int[] carbon_footprint_results) {
        for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

                for (int j=0; j<(int)data[i].length;j++) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Is it because I need to convert that `data[i]` into an integer before I can use it in the second for loop?

Comment: I see only empty loops. Did you paste the correct thing?

Comment: A `double` doesn't have a `length` field. It doesn't have any fields at all, and neither does an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gendarme said a `double` doesn't have a `length` field. In the second loop you have `data[i].length` which should throw that error. As you are asking for the `i`th `double` in the array and then asking for that `double`'s `length` which the compiler doesn't like.

You could try just taking off the `.length` field call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse a 2D double array, your function isgnature should be:

```
public static void calcCarbonFootprints(double[][] data, int[] carbon_footprint_results)
```

Comment: Good point *double[] - a 2D array of data for a populution where,*